# regex condition that returns only if a " [word]" does not trail at the end

Tags: python, regex

I'm new at regex, and somebody helpfully showed me the following a few minutes ago:

```
(?:^|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?=\D|$)
```

Now I would like to deploy its findings only if the strings it's looking for are not immediately trailed by a space and the word "Dog"

E.g., it would return a value if "2013-29883" is encountered, but not if "2013-29883 Dog" is encountered.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what language are you using? what environment? what version? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Python.  (And I saw regular-expressions.info mentioned quite a few times here, and have visited it and gotten some other valuable search/iteration information from the site, but I'm just not that up to speed on this parsing syntax yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex can be shortened by quite a few characters:

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?!\d)
```

And so that it doesn't match `2013-29883` followed by `Dog`, use another negative lookahead:

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?!\d)(?! Dog)
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is in c# then you can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class:

```
     string pattern = "(?:^|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{1,5}(?=\D|$)";

     if(Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
     {
        // Your code of a match
     }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I use C# for other stuff, but this one is a Python job.